# using protorpc message gives error: Excepted type absolute.path.to.MyMessage but found MyMessage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, protorpc

After forming my ProtoRPC message, I get the error:

Expected type 
class 'protorpc.messages.MHistoryActivityViewMessage'
for field items, 
found 
MHistoryActivityViewMessage\n body: u'Test Here'\n activity_id: 'WS-MHistory_ag9zfm1jYS1kZXJyaWNrLTFyGQsSEE1IaXN0b3J5QWN0aXZpdHkYsbyuBAw'

[...]

I have run across this issue many times where the expected type is 'absolute.path.to.MyMessage' but the found type is 'MyMessage'.

I'm stumped as to why I get this error.  I have gotten this error many times.  One workaround that sometimes works is moving the protorpc message definition higher up in the file seems.

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: What's found appears to be a string, not a class. Some wrong assignment somewhere? Hard to say without the code and the full traceback.

Comment: Here's a partial stack trace:

"/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/messages.py", line 1272, in validate_element
    (self.type, name, value, type(value)))
ValidationError: Expected type <class 'backend.network.mhistory.service.mhistory_messages.MHistoryActivityViewMessage'> for field items, found <MHistoryActivityViewMessage
 activity_id: 'WS-MHistory_ag9zfm1jYS1kZXJyaWNrLTFyGQsSEE1IaXN0b3J5QWN0aXZpdHkYsbyuBAw'
> (type <class 'network.mhistory.service.mhistory_messages.MHistoryActivityViewMessage'>)

Comment: Why is the type 'backend.network.mhistory.service.mhistory_messages.MHistoryActivityViewMessage' considered different from 'network.mhistory.service.mhistory_messages.MHistoryActivityViewMessage'?